# Ionic bar-header padding-top when status bar is hidden

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar

I have a problem using the bar-header component of the ionic-framework. I always have a padding-top of a few pixels (see screenshot). I'm using the cordova plugin `org.apache.cordova.statusbar` to hide the status bar like this:

```
  if(window.StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.hide();  
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
  }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: status bar padding/margin]

Comment: Could you specify the problem a little more or add a codepen that illustrates the problem?

Comment: when you look at the above screenshot you can see a slightly padding above the bar-light text where usually the status bar is located. When I'm viewing the same application in the web browser I don't have that problem. I'm not able to do a codepen since this issue occurs only in the iPhone emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed the plugin correctly it should be enough to just call

```
ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
```

right after you hide the statusbar.

This should probably remove the space at top of your app.

Comment: What's the difference between this and Platform.fullScreen(true, true)? much obliged

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite these ionic css rules in your main.css. This fixed the problem for me:

```
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader).item-input-inset .item-input-wrapper {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
}
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader) > * {
    margin-top: 0px; 
}
```